# Gradient fill shape file according to longitude

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-sf

I'd like to have my map fill based on longitude (east-west), not a single colour, but can't seem to be able to specify the object value for fill as the shape file is a multipolygon.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

MY_map<-read_sf("gadm36_MYS_0.shp")
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = MY_map, aes(fill=longitude))+
  scale_color_gradient(low= "#1E88E5",high="#D81B60",  limits=c(100, 120))

> MY_map
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 99.64072 ymin: 0.85372 xmax: 119.2697 ymax: 7.380556
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  GID_0 NAME_0                                                                                  geometry
  <chr> <chr>                                                                         <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
1 MYS   Malaysia (((111.2831 1.386488, 111.2837 1.386235, 111.2844 1.386343, 111.2851 1.386384, 111.2...
```

Lower longitudes should start with colour `#1E88E5` and gradate to `#D81B60`

I have tried extracting the coordinates using and inserting that in to no avail as well

```
my_coordinates<-st_coordinates(MY_map)
```

I'm sure there is an easy fix but I can't seem to be able to figure it out, and would appreciate some pointers here!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here `MY_map` is a single geometry, so in the actual form it is not possible to accomplish what you want.

My suggestion is to create a grid with `st_make_grid()`, that would create several regular `POLYGONS` covering the extent of Malaysia, extract the coordinates from that object and plot that altogether. See:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# For reproducibility, using giscoR
MY_map <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = "MYS")


MY_map
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 99.64621 ymin: 0.86449 xmax: 119.2038 ymax: 7.35131
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>     CNTR_ID NAME_ENGL ISO3_CODE CNTR_NAME FID                       geometry
#> 148      MY  Malaysia       MYS  Malaysia  MY MULTIPOLYGON (((117.8959 4....

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = MY_map)
```

[image]

Now we create the grid that we would use for plotting. The cellsize here is
0.5 degrees, but you can experiment this (i.e. use 1 for larger polygons)

```r
# Create a grid (cellsize c(0.5,0.5) means half degree, you may want to 
# adjust it to get a finer grid)
MY_grid <- st_make_grid(MY_map, cellsize = c(0.5, 0.5))

# Check
ggplot(MY_map) +
  geom_sf(fill = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = MY_grid, fill = NA)
```

[image]

Last step: Extract the longitude and also mask the grid to the shape of the country, so cells outside Malaysia are removed.

```r
# Get centroids and add longitude as feature
lons <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(MY_grid, warn = FALSE))[, 1]

# Create the sf object with longitudes as feature
MY_grid_final <- st_sf(longitude = lons, geometry = MY_grid) |>
  # Use the shape of the country as mask to remove outside celss
  st_intersection(st_geometry(MY_map))
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout
#> all geometries

MY_grid_final
#> Simple feature collection with 172 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 99.64621 ymin: 0.8644944 xmax: 119.2038 ymax: 7.35131
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#>    longitude                       geometry
#> 8   103.3962 POLYGON ((103.6312 1.364492...
#> 9   103.8962 POLYGON ((104.1462 1.341534...
#> 10  104.3962 MULTIPOLYGON (((104.2477 1....
#> 21  109.8962 POLYGON ((110.1462 1.203172...
#> 22  110.3962 POLYGON ((110.6462 0.896961...
#> 23  110.8962 POLYGON ((111.1462 1.031521...
#> 24  111.3962 POLYGON ((111.6462 1.010502...
#> 25  111.8962 POLYGON ((112.1462 1.218895...
#> 26  112.3962 POLYGON ((112.2177 1.364496...
#> 28  113.3962 POLYGON ((113.6462 1.252766...


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = MY_map, fill=NA, color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = MY_grid_final, aes(fill = longitude), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#1E88E5", high = "#D81B60", limits = c(100, 120))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like it should work, but am currently running into an issue where I can't seem to use the shape of the country as mask to remove outside cells. R doesn't seem to read `|>` as intended, and realised that this works in the latest version of R but am currently running 3.6

`> MY_grid_final <- st_sf(longitude = lons, geometry = MY_grid) |> Error: unexpected '>' in "MY_grid_final <- st_sf(longitude = lons, geometry = MY_grid) |>" 
> st_intersection(st_geometry(MY_map))
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar`

Comment: Figured it out without the pipe and now works as intended!

`MY_poly <- st_sf(longitude = lons, geometry = MY_grid)
MY_grid_final<-st_intersection(MY_poly,st_geometry(MY_map))`